# Should Content-Security-Policy header be applied to all resources?

Tags: content-security-policy, websecurity

Is it necessary to apply the Content-Security-Policy Header to all resources on your domain (images/CSS/JavaScript) or just web pages?

For example, I noticed that https://content-security-policy.com/images/csp-book-cover-sm.png has a CSP header.

[image: I noticed that https://content-security-policy.com/images/csp-book-cover-sm.png has a CSP header.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is only necessary to apply it to web pages that are rendered in a browser, as CSP controls the allowed sources for content, framing etc of such pages. Typically you will only need to set it on non-redirect responses with content type as "text/html". As CSP can be set in a meta tag, another way to look at it is that it only makes sense on responses that could include a meta tag.

As it is often simpler or only possible to just add a response header to all responses, CSPs are often applied to all content types and codes even though they are not strictly needed. Additionally it is recommended to add a CSP with a strict frame-ancestors to REST APIs to prevent drag-and-drop style clickjacking attacks, see https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/REST_Security_Cheat_Sheet.html#security-headers.

Comment: Do you have a docs link for the fact that CSP is only needed for content and framing? I assume that mean it's not needed for JS, JSON, images, etc.?

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't find one right now, but it is a CONTENT security policy, so the name implies quite a bit. There is real need to apply it to the types of content you mention, but it might be done anyway because it is added to all responses or because scanners give bad grades because they don't understand better.